# over a wide range of temperature or temperatures

Tags: grammatical-number, singular-they

I am confused with singular and plural words sometimes. For example as the title, I should use **over a wide range of *temperature*** or **over a wide range of *temperatures***. One sentence example is 
This model is accurate over a wide range of temperature(s).

Comment: @Phil '... features' is non-negotiable (it's the verb-form following that's up for debate), unlike ' ... temperature/s' here.

Comment: [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+wide+range+of+temperature%2Ca+wide+range+of+temperatures&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20wide%20range%20of%20temperature%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20wide%20range%20of%20temperatures%3B%2Cc0) seem to show that both are used, and preferences have fluctuated (though there may be some false positives with attributive 'temperature').

Answer (score 1):

Your choice of **temperature** or **temperatures** can add information to your sentence.

For example, if you have the ability to set the temperature to discrete values, as you might have in a computer program, then the plural form helps to convey that. It also applies if the temperatures have been set in experiments or tests, even if these are not explicit. A motor oil, for example, might be usable over a range of air temperatures.

On the other hand, if the temperature can vary continuously, and is not settable, nor being sampled at discrete points, and if the *range* is more central to the thought, then the singular form can help.

For example: “The range of temperature across the stage was exactly opposite to the range of illumination. If you could see your music on the stand in front of you, you were probably wrapped up too tightly to play it.”

In most cases you can use either form. However, because we humans are so fond of measuring things, *range of temperatures* will often sound more natural.